# Using an Enumerator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript, activex

I have the following VBScript code, which I would like to express instead in JavaScript:

```
Sub GxUIProxyVB_OnLogon 

    Dim EntityProxy

    For Each EntityProxy In GxUIProxyVB.ListEntityProxy 
        MsgBox EntityProxy.Name 
    Next 

End Sub
```

To give context this code is a post-logon event handler of an ActiveX control's logon event.  The ActiveX control is hosted in a web page running in Internet Explorer 8. The user of the web page triggers this code's execution by successfully logging on via the ActiveX control's logon mechanism.

In the code *GxUIProxyVB* is a reference to the ActiveX control's object embedded in the DOM via an HTML  element.

This is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
function GxUIProxyVB::OnLogon()
{
    var EntityProxy; 
    // For Each EntityProxy In GxUIProxyVB.ListEntityProxy 
    //     alert(EntityProxy.Name);
    // Next 
}
```

I have commented out the part I am struggling with: **enumerating the value of *GxUIProxyVB.ListEntityProxy*.**

This screen shot from IE8's watch list shows the members of the *ListEntityProxy* object
[image: Screen capture of IE 8's watch list]

As a workaround I realize I could just leave the code in VBScript as the users will probably only be using Internet Explorer to access this content, but I'd rather have it in JavaScript for code maintainablity. (I don't want future web developers who maintain this code to need to be proficient in VBScript.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use an [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ch9zb09%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object:

```
function gxUIProxyVB_OnLogon() {
    var entityProxy; 
    for (var enr = new Enumerator(GxUIProxyVB.ListEntityProxy); !enr.atEnd(); enr.moveNext()) {
        entityProxy = enr.item();
        alert(entityProxy.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a whirl. I suspected it was something like that, but wasn't aware of how you did it in JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome! The code now executes exactly as it did in VBScript. Thank you very much.

Comment: And thank you also for teaching me something new. I was ignornant about the Enumerator type.

Comment: It’s one of the Microsoft-specific bits of JScript. You’re welcome. :-)

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that either. Glad you pointed that out. Thanks again.